# Check if subcategory exists in current category

Tags: category

I have the following category setup in my  magento store:

```
store root
|
bedroom    kitchen     bathroom    
|            |            |            
furniture  furniture   furniture         
lighting   lighting    misc
misc
```

I need to be able to check if the category `misc` exists as a subcategory in my current category or not, and if so show a particular block.

So if i was in the kitchen category it would not show but in bedroom and bathroom it would.

How can i do this this check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the list of subcategories of a category like this:

```
$currentCategoryId = 10; 
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1) //only active categories
    ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $currentCategoryId);
```

If you want to check if only a specific category is present...in your case with the name 'misc' just add an additional filter to the code above:

```
$currentCategoryId = 10; 
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1) //only active categories
    ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $currentCategoryId)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('name', 'misc') //filter by name
    ->setPage(1,1) //set a limit to the collection
    ->addAttributeToSelect('url_key');
```

And you don't even need to load the full collection. You just need to check if the collection from above has at least 1 item in it.

```
if ($collection->getSize() == 1) {
    // 'misc' exists
    $url = $collection->getFirstItem()->getUrl();
}
else {
    // no 'misc' subcategory for you.
}
```

Comment: Spot on, thank you. One last thing where you have `//'misc' sub category exists` and i would be showing my block, how can i get the link of that particular misc category from `$collection`?

Comment: @odd_duck. I've changed a bit the code and now you can get the subcategory url also.

Comment: @Marius You can get current category id by using this  <?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId(); ?> or   
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('product_list')->getCategoryId();   
Then why don't you ..?

Comment: @Elavarasan. I didn't know the context where the category id was needed. I just put the code as a proof of concept. The source of the category id is not important. You can even get it like this `Mage::registry('current_category')->getId()`.